# Installing/Importing Python Packages for Web.py

Tags: python, web-deployment, web.py

I have built a website with web.py and it runs fine on my local machine, but I am moving it to my host server and I am having some difficulty with importing the packages that it uses, specifically BeautifulSoup and Matplotlib. I am not sure how to install the packages from source into a specific directory so that my script will recognize them with the import package command. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am pretty new to web dev in python - probably obvious from the question!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/), it lets you install all required Python modules in your chosen directory.

Create a virtualenv, install all required modules in it and then run your server in this virtualenv's environment. That's it.

Comment: Thanks, I created the env, activated it, and installed web.py, BeautifulSoup, and Matplotlib in the env as specified here:
http://lars.la/webpy_and_virtualenv.html.

Now, I am wondering what I need to do to my app to be deployed using the new virtual environment. I deployed it originally using LightTPD with FastCGI as specified here:
http://webpy.org/deployment.

Comment: Just to note, I have the env and app in two different directories.

Comment: I have decided to try installing to a local dir and I now have the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718015/importing-and-using-beautifulsoup-for-web-app)