# Importing and Using BeautifulSoup for Web App

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-deployment

I am currently trying to use BeautifulSoup for a Web App and I have installed the beautifulsoup4 egg in a local dir with `easy_install --install-dir=PATH_TO_DIR beautifulsoup4`, but when I run my app I'm getting the current error that I don't know what to do about:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
File "/home/ryanefoley/py_libs/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.6.egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 186
  if ((isinstance(markup, bytes) and not b' ' in markup)
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Note, I am importing the module in my python script with:

```
egg_path='/home/ryanefoley/py_libs/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.6.egg'
sys.path.append(egg_path)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: `b' '` is a Python 3 syntax, but your egg says `py2.6`, interesting

Comment: Anyway the first you should do is start using `virtualenv`, the canonical way of installing libraries per-project.

Comment: I am using Python 2.6

Comment: I don't know how to connect my app to the virtualenv, but maybe I should figure that out...

Comment: How do you normally run your app? Simplest you can do is use the `python` binary from the env, or source the `activate` script in bash and run it using `PATH`'s Python normally

Comment: I set up my application on dream host with the following first set of instructions using CGI: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Web.py